# Using grep with multiple strings but each string needs to have a seperate output

Tags: search, grep, find

Is it possible to use grep to look for specific strings, and have output file for each matched string.
( I use cygwin )

What I want to do in details:

- Look into only specific files which can be .txt and .log extension only. (Also specific filenames like *fruit.txt")
- When there is a hit, copy 2 lines BEFORE and 2 lines AFTER into the results file
- For each matched string like "APPLE" or "PEAR" copy tthe results into the belonging results file. Apple goes into apple.txt and pear goes into pear.txt .etc etc
- I have over 30 different strings what I want to look for.

A regular grep should look like this for fruits and another for meat:

```
grep -r -A 2 -B 2 --include={vegetables,fruits,meat,basket,*fruit*}.{txt,log} "\.apple\.\|pear\." > D:\fruits_results.txt
grep -r -A 2 -B 2 --include={vegetables,fruits,meat,basket,*fruit*}.{txt,log} "\.bacon\.\|steak\." > D:\meats_results.txt
```

But I want to combine together all 30 search into one script where grep will run just once, and write the related results into the related files. Because the data is over 10TB this is why I want to use grep, I think that's the fastest solution on this ammount of data.

My idea was this, but for some reason doesn't work. I think passing data from find to grep is braking it and ending up with 0 results.

```
#!/bin/bash

keywords=("\.APPLE\." "\.PEAR\.")
search_directory="F:/Search"
result_directory="F:/Output"

# Create a temporary directory to store the combined results
tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d)

# Search for files using the find command and execute grep for pattern matching
find "$search_directory" -type f \( -name "*fruits.txt" -o -name "*meat.txt" -o -name "*vegetables.txt" *fruits.log" -o -name "*meat.log" -o -name "*vegetables.log" \) -exec grep -E -o -w -A 2 -B 2 -H -n "$(IFS="|"; echo "${keywords[*]}")" {} + > "$tmp_dir/results.txt"

# Process the results, verify, and save them into separate files
while IFS=':' read -r file line_num line; do
  for keyword in "${keywords[@]}"; do
    if [[ $line =~ $keyword ]]; then
      output_file="${keyword//[^A-Z0-9a-z]/_}.txt"
      echo "File: $file"
      echo "Line: $line_num"
      echo "Match: $line"
      echo
      echo "File: $file" >> "$result_directory/$output_file"
      echo "Line: $line_num" >> "$result_directory/$output_file"
      echo "$line" >> "$result_directory/$output_file"
      echo >> "$result_directory/$output_file"
      break
    fi
  done
done < "$tmp_dir/results.txt"

# Remove the temporary directory
rm -r "$tmp_dir"
```

In javascript this is a working almost perfect script, but way slower than using grep, and no regex can be used for the file "SEARCH_FILE_FILTER":

```
const { readdirSync, appendFileSync, createReadStream } = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const SEARCH_FOLDER = "F:/Search/";
const SEARCH_FILE_FILTER = ['.txt', '.log']; (sadly no regex can be used here)
const FIND_PATTERNS = ['fruit', 'meat'];
const RESULT_FOLDER = "D:/";

const getDirContent = async(dirPath) => {
    console.log(`Reading directory: ${dirPath}`);

    const folders = [];
    const files = [];
    const items = readdirSync(dirPath, { withFileTypes: true });

    for (const item of items) {
        if (item.isDirectory()) {
            folders.push(`${dirPath}/${item.name}`);
        } else if (SEARCH_FILE_FILTER.find(filter => item.name.includes(filter))) {
            files.push(`${dirPath}/${item.name}`);
        }
    }

    if (files.length > 0) {
        await search(files);
    }
    if (folders.length > 0) {
        for (const f of folders) {
            await getDirContent(f);
        }
    }
};

const searchAt = (filePath) => {
    const arr = [];
    const findings = {
    };
    for (const pattern of FIND_PATTERNS) {
        findings[pattern] = [];
    }

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: createReadStream(filePath),
            crlfDelay: Infinity,
        });
        
        line = 0;
        rl.on('line', (line) => {
            arr.push(line);
        });
    
        rl.on('close', () => {
            for ([index, line] of arr.entries()) {
                for (const pattern of FIND_PATTERNS) {
                    if (line.includes(pattern)) {
                        findings[pattern].push(`\n\n###### Found at: ${filePath} (line:${index}) #####`);
                        if ((index - 1) > 0) {
                            findings[pattern].push(arr[index-1]);
                        }
                        findings[pattern].push(line);
                        if (arr.length >= (index + 1)) {
                            findings[pattern].push(arr[index+1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            resolve(findings);
        });
    });
}

const writeToDisk = (findingList) => {
    for (const findings of findingList) {
        for (const [pattern, value] of Object.entries(findings)) {
            appendFileSync(`${RESULT_FOLDER}/${pattern}.log`, value.join('\n'));
        }
    }
}

const search = async(fileList) => {
    const p = [];
    for (const filePath of fileList) {
        p.push(searchAt(filePath));
    }

    const findingList = await Promise.all(p);
    writeToDisk(findingList);
}


(async() => {
    await getDirContent(SEARCH_FOLDER);
    console.log(`Done`);
})();
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You asked "Is it possible to use grep to look for specific strings, and have output file for each matched string." - that's more than just doing `g/re/p` as grep is designed to do so you shouldn't be considering trying to use grep for it, use awk instead. Once you provide a [mcve] we can help you.